Are Golems affected by the command spell?
Most golems have the following information in their bio text:

Blind Obedience. When its creator or possessor is on hand to command it, a golem performs flawlessly. If the golem is left without instructions or is incapacitated, it continues to follow its last orders to the best of its ability. When it can’t fulfill its orders, a golem might react violently — or stand and do nothing. A golem that has been given conflicting orders sometimes alternates between them.
A golem can’t think or act for itself. Though it understands its
commands perfectly, it has no grasp of language beyond that
understanding, and can’t be reasoned with or tricked with words.

This is mostly flavor text, but say I target a golem with Command, ordering it to grovel. However, the Golem had been given the command by its creator to fend off any intruders, such as myself. Because my command to make the golem grovel conflicts with its command to fend me off, due to its Blind Obedience would it be able to ignore my command even if it fails the save?
Also just as a side note, Command is not a charm spell, so I know a golem isn't immune to it due to charm immunity.

I've gone ahead and removed the 2024 tag from your question as we don't have the requisite monster manual for that version yet. If this conflicts with your intent, can you please edit the question to provide more info to allow it to be answerable under the 2024 rules?

@Pyrotechnical, I added it back because the 2024 spell, which is relevant to the answer, should be backwards compatible with the creatures.

Please limit questions to one system only. This isn’t a comparison, but an honest question about how the rules work with an system. Therefore, it should just have one system, and I have removed the 2024 tag.

@NotArch, the OP originally included both systems in the question, and there are plenty of previous examples of questions that include both systems.

Note: "Most golems have the following information in their bio text" because this text appears in the Monster Manual section on golems. D&D Beyond helpfully provides this text under the stat block of all the monster from that section, but to be clear, the primary source is the MM. (I'm not sure if this will matter to the answer, but I figured I'd note it regardless.)

I have again removed the 2024 tag. Separate systems should have separate questions. OP quotes 2014. So let’s keep it to 2014. When the new MM comes out, then they can ask about that when and if they are still confused.

RAW, the Golem is affected by Command
2014's Command says:

You speak a one-word command to a creature you can see within range. The target must succeed on a Wisdom saving throw or follow the command on its next turn. The spell has no effect if the target ... doesn't understand your language, or if your command is directly harmful to it.

The Golem understands the languages of its creator

Languages Understands the languages of its creator...

So, a command in one of those languages should qualify.
Realistically, a ruling on this could go either way, and you should talk to your DM about it beforehand. The clause

Though it understands its commands perfectly, it has no grasp of language beyond that understanding, and can’t be reasoned with or tricked with words.

could function as a caveat, since it does seem to indicate that the Golem might only understand the commands of its creator.
In contrast, 2024's Command curiously removed the restriction that the creature must understand the language of the command, however it limits the possible commands to a small set of options:

You speak a one-word command to a creature you can see within range. The target must succeed on a Wisdom saving throw or follow the command on its next turn. Choose the command from these options...

So, the 2024 spell should affect the golem, regardless.

Personally, I think this is a really cool, creative application of Command and can lead to interesting role play opportunities.

Command Can Affect Golems
The spell Command only stipulates that the target must understand languages, which most golems do - even if they can't speak. They're INT is seemingly always at least 3 which is the minimum for understanding language, and their WIS is usually towards the middle of the scale which makes them capable of perception.
Command does not confer the following conditions (Golem Immunities):

Charmed
Exhaustion
Frightened
Paralyzed
Petrified
Poisoned

The sample actions include "prone" and I'm sure "grappled" or "restrained" can get in there but they are not in the list. That first one is the most important one to me of that list since we're talking about an Enchantment spell.
With language, let's visit the line you stated (also from MM1 2014 pg167)

A golem can’t think or act for itself. Though it understands its commands perfectly, it has no grasp of language beyond that understanding, and can’t be reasoned with or tricked with words.

To me, a spell like Command fits perfectly into those cracks. To me it seems akin to instructing a dog. It knows commands/tricks individually but you can't conventionally "reason". An exception to this may be the Flesh Golem with the berserker safety with "persuasion".
Where the rub can occur, is that golems generally have "Magical Resistance", which gives them advantage on the save. A given generic golem is running with their WIS save being a flat d20 roll, so that may not mean much.
I don't seem to have any sample golems in 2024 to reference, but it removes almost all of the constraints. No listing of "understands", "undead", or "harmful", although Magic Resistance does still exist.
